# Block login page for logged in users on Symfony3

Tags: symfony, php-7, symfony-security

I made a registration/login form example on Symfony3.

After user logged in still can access `login.html.twig`

How can i control this on `security.yml` or redirect on `login.html.twig`?

my access_control;

```
access_control:
            - { path: ^/registration-form-submission$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/(login|register)$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: I did it. @Veve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added the following code to controllers RegistrationController and LoginController:

```
if ($this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
    return new RedirectResponse('/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried something like :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/registration-form-submission$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/(login|register)$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, allow_if: "not has_role('ROLE_USER')" }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

[documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#securing-by-an-expression)

Comment: It does not work for me but i found a solution and edited post.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 4 if you extends from *AbstractController*:

```
public function register(Request $request){
    if ($this->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('/');
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i think it's better to use IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY instead of ROLE_USER.